# Handling ActivityRecognition.API intents while app is inactive

Tags: android, design-patterns, google-play-services, activity-recognition

I'm looking for the general design to implement this:

I want to register to the ActivityRecognition API to receive regular updates in a IntentService called from time to time by this API, while everything else in my App is completely inactive (the goal here is to avoid draining too much battery power on the device).

The issue is that with the new ActivityRecognition API design, it is tied to a GooglePlayServices client, like this for example:

```
ActivityRecognition.ActivityRecognitionApi.requestActivityUpdates(
    myGoogleApiClient, 
    3000L, 
    myActivityRecognitionPendingIntent);
```

And logically, this client disappears if the Activity or Service that created it is destroyed, resulting of the loss of any ActivityRecognition updates.

Obviously everything can go well if I keep a Service (or Activity) alive, holding constantly the GooglePlayServices client used to initiate the ActivityRecognition API (*myGoogleApiClient* in this example)… But that is what I want to avoid…

How can this be achieved?

Comment: you could create  a service running in foreground mode.  it would keep an notification icon.  there may be better approaches but this is what comes to mind...

Comment: Thank you. But yes, that is already what I do, but sadly keeping a service constantly awaken drains more battery, and I'm trying to implement an efficient design = beeing awaken from time to time just enough to gather and collect data, then go back to sleep.

Comment: then you should look at the alarm manager and the tradeoffs there, please see
https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look at the alarm manager and the tradeoffs there, please see https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

If the API auto-wakes up only at the appropriate time, a much more efficient solution is to try a broadcast receiver. If you require the device to remain awake why you are processing, you should look into https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html

Comment: An AlarmManager that would run every 3 seconds to build + connect to a new GoogleAPIClient each time, re-starting the ActivityRecognition API... for only 1 shot… and so on forever... This sounds odd written like this, but this is maybe more efficient than a Service always running in background? Do your have any clue about it?

Comment: wow every 3 seconds AND you want to be power efficient? i'm not sure if those two can live in the same sentence... you'll need to test and i'm not aware of the cost of "restarting the activity recognition API".  the google api connect is MOSTLY free and can be done totally locally by the google play services framework, so not super worried about that. But just waking up every 3 secs is a ton. You want that even if the device is asleep? Do you need a wakelock?

Comment: That is a good point: as documented, the ActivityRecognitionAPI would go asleep and wakeup itself when needed, that is why beeing awaken by it should be power-efficient. However if we go with the AlarmManager, it involves putting an arbitrary delay (my 3 seconds) to wake it up (because we have no idea what is going on otherwise) without having the benefit of the self-intelligence of the ActivityRecognition API… 
To say the truth I cannot believe that Google did not think about it, because it is designed as if it was made for such use cases (?)

Comment: Ah so it auto-wakes up? Then DEFINITELY do NOT use an alarm service. Does it issue an event when it wakes up? If yes, you should look into broadcast receivers. If you need to make sure the device does not go to sleep while you are doing the processing, you can use a wakeful one. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html

Comment: Yes it is well designed for this...
By the time you have the kindness to keep this conversation, I'm seeing the ActivityRecognition re-firing events by itself, although it had stopped...

There is definately something weird / that I do not understand with the design of the GoogleApiClient: how can it run as the client holder is "dead" ? I have no idea, and cannot find any precise info about it…

Comment: [This SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30957821/1720332) is related to this and quite instructive… As you mentioned I will investigate the WakefulBroadcastReceiver way… Thank you!

Comment: thanks for accepting and thanks for the link to the related answer, very good info in there that i can use in other situations! :)

Answer (score 1):

After further testing, and using the updated GooglePlayServices (9.0.2) this looks an impossible task.
I solved it by creating a sticky service that stays always in background and does *only* one thing: maintaining a GoogleApiClient connection alive. Hopefully this won't drain too much power…

Without doing it, killing what was handling the GoogleApiClient was resulting in weird and inconsistent bugs and behaviors depending on the Android version and on the device running it: 30% of the time it was working fine, otherwise the App was crashing, so definately not reliable.

At the end, it looks like the GooglePlayServices are designed this way: we need to keep alive a connection to the GoogleApiClient with a background activity or service, even if this sounds a bit odd, there are maybe some good reasons to act like this.

Answer (score 0):

Use Activity Transition API instead.